# coupling between objects CBO representation in latex

Tags: math-mode

Could anyone, please help me in writing the following discrete mathematics equations in latex:
[image]

where C is the set of all classes in the system and uses(x, y)
is a predicate that is true if there is a relationship between
the two classes x and y e.g. an attribute or local variable of
type y in x.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try? Is there something specific you don't know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose that you like. There are online many guide to use `LaTeX`. Regards.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$CBO(c)=\lvert\{d\in C -\{c\}\mid \mathrm{uses}(c,d)\vee  \mathrm{uses}(d,c) \}\rvert$
\[CBO(c)=\lvert\{d\in C -\{c\}\mid \mathrm{uses}(c,d)\vee  \mathrm{uses}(d,c) \}\rvert\]
$CBO(c)=\lvert\{d\in C -\{c\}\mid uses(c,d)\vee  uses(d,c) \}\rvert$
\[CBO(c)=\lvert\{d\in C -\{c\}\mid uses(c,d)\vee  uses(d,c) \}\rvert\]
\[CBO(C)=\sum_{d\in C}{CBO(d)}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: @Mai You're welcome.